# Determining the permutation of two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can i find the permutation of two strings? Like for example if we have :

permuted_strings('hey','eyh')

the permuted list we should get is [ 1,2,0]

Comment: `A` and `B` are not strings, they are lists of strings. IF we treat them as strings based on the first item in the list, how is the output `[1,2,0]` calculated? Additionally what have you tried to do to solve this issue?

Comment: From what I saw, OP is basically just printing the corresponding index of permutation of list

Comment: the function must look like this for example /  permuted_strings(['hey','eyh'])=[1,2,0] and yes i should print the corresonding index

Comment: I don't understand how the input is calculated..., sorry

Comment: i edited the question to make it clearer i mixed it up a bit before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for your simple example. However, just like the answer of Aku it will need some changes when characters occur multiple times.

```py
def get_permutations_by_index(str_a, str_b):
    return [str_a.index(char) for char in str_b]

def get_index_permutations(str_a, str_b):
    indices = []
    for char_b in str_b:
        for index, char_a in enumerate(str_a):
            if char_a == char_b:
                indices.append(index)
                break
    return indices

# If you are checking large strings, you could use the dictionary based approach 
# inspired by Aku's answer (his answer returns the last seen index of chars)
def get_index_permutations_by_dict(str_a, str_b):
    indices = {}
    for index, char in enumerate(str_a):
        if char not in indices:
             # if char occurs multiple times in str_a, we just want the first index
            indices[char] = index    
    return [indices[char] for char in str_b]


get_permutations_by_index('hey', 'eyh')
>> [1, 2, 0]

get_index_permutations('hey', 'eyh')
>> [1, 2, 0]

get_index_permutations_by_dict('hey', 'eyh')
>> [1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: The rough part about this solution is that it's O(n^2), so if you have really long strings, it will take a very long time. However, I guess they can only get so long, since there's a limited number of characters.

Comment: I see your point. But it will be a little bit faster, because it doesn't consider multiple occurrences of characters. I will add your dict based approach as an alternative.

Comment: Since @Aku's answer did only return the last seen index of each character I slighlty changed his idea

Comment: can you please explain to me enumerate function , since i am a beginner in coding.

Comment: [Python Enumerate](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Comment: i kind of understood enumerate but can we write this code without it and other way that Aku. I want to have a simpler way

Comment: Simpler? I don't think this is a hard way at all

Comment: Even simpler would be using `index()`. See the edit of my answer. It is the first option now

Comment: i cant yet still how enumerate works. from what i have understood it assigns each value in the list with its index correct?

Answer (score 1):

Note: There's no reason to put your strings in lists. They already act like lists, so you can do `A[2]`, for example.

Assuming all characters in your string are unique, this is pretty easily solvable.

```
A = "hey"
B = "eyh"
```

We can make a dict that maps each character to its index:

```
d = {val:idx for idx, val in enumerate(A)}
```

Now, we can map each character in `B` to its index in `A`:

```
o = [d[val] for val in B]
```

Edit:
You can make this into a simple function as follows.

```
def get_perm_idxs(A, B):
    d = {val:idx for idx, val in enumerate(A)}
    return [d[val] for val in B]
```

Comment: i am having trouble understanding your code , the function must look like this for example / permuted_strings(['hey','eyh'])=[1,2,0]